# DMS to Lat Long Conversion in PHP

Tags: latitude-longitude, dms

This code is working for lat long conversion

/*lat start*/

$txt_lat = "2306.2405,S";

$latFirst = substr($txt_lat,0,2);

$getLatMinSec = substr($txt_lat,2,9).str_split(',')[0];

$getLatDirection = substr($txt_lat,10,11);

$latSecond = $getLatMinSec/60;

$finalLat = floatval($latFirst) + floatval($latSecond);

if($getLatDirection == "S"){

```
$finalLat = "-".$finalLat;
```

}

echo $finalLat;

/*long start*/

$txt_long = "07235.6583,W";

$longFirst =    substr($txt_long,0,3);

$getLongMinSecL = substr($txt_long,3,11).str_split(',')[0];

$getLongDirection = substr($txt_long,11,12);

$longSecond = $getLongMinSecL/60;

$finalLong = floatval($longFirst) + floatval($longSecond);

if($getLongDirection == "W"){

```
$finalLong = "-".$finalLong;
```

}

echo $finalLong;

=========== Output ================

"latitude": "-23.104008333333"

"longitude": "-72.594305"

Comment: "This code is working for lat long conversion" --- that surely is not true simply because the very first line is syntax error: `$txt_lat = 2306.2405,S;`

Comment: Hello It's working just i forgot to apply double quote in string.